# How to list my Ranger tagged folders and go to any of them?

Tags: file-management

In [Ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) I know that the list of tagged elements is located at `~/.config/ranger/tagged`
So, what is a fast way to list and open them?

Comment: How does that file/directory looks and what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

So, that file looks like this:

```
/path/to/directory
t:/path/to/another/directory
/path/to/some/file
...
```

You can simply view it in Vim with:

```
:view ~/.config/ranger/tagged
```

and use `:help gf` or `:help <C-w>f` to jump to the directory/file under your cursor.

Comment: Do you know of a way in which I don't have to leave Ranger?

Comment: I need more context.